How do you animate a new item being added to the list if your list is built from a SwiftData Query
Say you have a query of a SwiftData object and you populate a ForEach using it:
@Query(animation: .easeIn) var workouts: [Workout]

List {
    Section(header: workouts.isEmpty ? Text("") : Text("Workouts")) {
        ForEach(workouts) { workout in
            NavigationLink(value: workout) {

and in there you have a button that will duplicate a workout and append it to the list via insertion into modelContext:
if showDuplicateButton {
    Button {
        //the workout copy method uses the exercises copy method to copy all exercises which itself does the same for its sets
        let newWorkout = workout.copy()
        modelContext.insert(newWorkout)
        
    }
}

how would you make it so this new item in the list comes in with animation instead of just posing into existence? so far I have tried withAnimation and it does nothing:
withAnimation(.spring()){
    modelContext.insert(newWorkout)
}


I don't know why this question was downvoted, it seems very valid to me. Animation related concepts are not easy to grasp initially and you've shown you've tried something that is actually in the right direction. However, you did provide incomplete code that cannot simply be copied, pasted and corrected. You should provide a reproducible example so we can actually test things before providing an answer. As such, the code in the solution may not be fully working.
Typically, if you want things to animate on a click of a button, wrap the respective action/code in the withAnimation() call:
if showDuplicateButton {
    Button {
        withAnimation(.spring) { // <-- here, wrap button in withAnimation
            //the workout copy method uses the exercises copy method to copy all exercises which itself does the same for its sets
            let newWorkout = workout.copy()
            modelContext.insert(newWorkout)
        }
    }
}

If you want to control how the animated element should be animated, use a .transition() modifier on the respective view.
In your case, it may be better to allow the container to animate its contents, whenever the data changes, something like this:
List {
    Section(header: workouts.isEmpty ? Text("") : Text("Workouts")) {
        ForEach(workouts) { workout in
            NavigationLink(value: workout) {
    //... you provided incomplete code here
} 
.animation(.spring, value: workouts) // <-- here, define the animation that should happen when the monitored value changes

However:
Your main issue here is likely not with how you define the animation, but with the fact that you're trying to animate a List row. It seems List rows are not that flexible in this regard. So unless you really need a List, you could change to a VStack to gain control over the animation and transition.
Here's a complete code that shows the use of .animation and .transition in two scenarios - when the loop is inside a List and when it is not (outside of it).
If you select the Slide option, you will notice the bottom (VStack) list animates with the respective transition, whereas the actual List does not.

struct ListInsertAnimation: View {
    
    let data: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    
    @State private var elements: [String] = []
    @State private var transitionType: TransitionType = .opacity
    @State private var reset: [String] = []
    
    enum TransitionType {
        case opacity, slide, scale
    }
    
    private var transition: AnyTransition {
        switch (transitionType) {
            case .opacity:
                return AnyTransition.opacity
            case .slide:
                return AnyTransition.slide
            case .scale:
                return AnyTransition.scale
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List {
            HStack {
                Picker("Transition", selection: $transitionType){
                    Text("Opacity").tag(.opacity as TransitionType)
                    Text("Slide").tag(.slide as TransitionType)
                    Text("Scale").tag(.scale as TransitionType)
                }
                .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                .fixedSize()
                
                Spacer()

                //Reset button (show if at least one element was added
                if elements.count > 3 {
                    let _ = print("elemenmts is : \(elements as AnyObject) ")
                    let _ = print("reset is : \(reset as AnyObject) ")
                    Button {
                        elements = data
                    } label: {
                        Text("Reset")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .tint(.red)
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
                }
                
                //Add button
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.spring) {
                        elements.append("Foo")
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                }
                .buttonStyle(.borderless)
            }
            
            //Loop inside a list - transition has no effect
            ForEach(elements, id:\.self) {element in
                Text(element)
                    .transition(transition)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            //initialize working array
            elements = data
        }
        
        //Alternate example with loop not inside a list
        ForEach(elements, id:\.self) {element in
            Text(element)
                .transition(transition)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ListInsertAnimation()
}

